# Ruby on Rails html.erb formating and linting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, erb, lint, code-formatting

There seem to be no consensus on a formatter and a linters that can correctly be used for html.erb.
I tried erb_lint and it's super buggy. I tried prettier, but there seem to be no incentive to fix support. Other extensions simply don't work.
I don't want to get into too much detail. I just want to know if there's a consensus that I don't know about. For all I know, it's a PITA and there has to be a better way.

Thanks in advance.